# Knockout : Observable with Observables inside only updating in UI, but unchanged when passed to the server?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, knockout.js, signalr

I have this observable object, which has two observable properties inside :

```
self.matchModel = ko.observable();
```

**The Model looks like this :**

```
function toKnockOutObservable(data) {
    return {
        Id: data.Id,
        TeamId: data.TeamId,
        TeamName: data.TeamName,
        OpponentName: data.OpponentName,
        LocationName: data.LocationName,
        MatchDate: data.MatchDate,
        LiveScoreActivated: data.LiveScoreActivated,
        TeamScore: ko.observable(data.TeamScore),
        OpponentScore: ko.observable(data.OpponentScore)
    };
}
```

**The way i'm changing the data on the observable :**

```
 self.AddScoreToOpponentTeam = function () {
        self.matchModel().TeamScore(self.matchModel().TeamScore() + 1);
        taskHub.server.updateLiveScore(self.matchModel());
    }
```

**The Problem :**

The Knockout model is updated in the UI, and everything seems fine, but... when i'm passing the observable object to the server it hasn't changed at all.. (matchModel is the same as it was when first loaded)..

> Code which updates an observable property on the observable object : self.matchModel().TeamScore(self.matchModel().TeamScore() + 1);

So... what am i actually doing wrong here ?

---

### Updated : 09.02.2016 : 09:15 to show more code :

**Getting data filling knockout model with it :**

```
var url = 'api/MainPage/GetMatchById?matchId=' + matchId;

$.post(url,
    function (data) {
        model.livematch(data);
        console.log(data);
        model.matchModel(toKnockOutObservable(data));
    }, 'json');

ko.applyBindings(model, document.getElementById("livematch"));
```

**Filling knockout model with data :**

```
function toKnockOutObservable(data) {
    return {
        Id: data.Id,
        TeamId: data.TeamId,
        TeamName: data.TeamName,
        OpponentName: data.OpponentName,
        LocationName: data.LocationName,
        MatchDate: data.MatchDate,
        LiveScoreActivated: data.LiveScoreActivated,
        TeamScore: ko.observable(data.TeamScore),
        OpponentScore: ko.observable(data.OpponentScore)
    };
}
```

**The KO Viewmodel and click handler to modify TeamScore :**

```
var LiveMatchViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.livematch = ko.observable();
    self.matchModel = ko.observable();

    self.AddScoreToHomeTeam = function () {
        var teamScore = self.matchModel().TeamScore();  // Teamscore is 0 (OK)
        teamScore += 1;
        self.matchModel().TeamScore(teamScore);
        taskHub.server.updateLiveScore(self.matchModel()); // When passed to back-end TeamScore property is still 0 (WRONG).
        console.log("Ny teamscore verdi i modellen " + self.matchModel().TeamScore()); // Teamscore is now 1 (OK)
    }
```

**Parts of databinding in UI (Which works, and displays correct TeamScore after AddScoreToHomeTeam is clicked :**

```
<!--ko with: matchModel-->
    <%--// HOME TEAM--%>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="widget-container row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 widget-box">
                <div class="widget-content scrollable visible">
                    <div class="header">
                        <p>
                            <!--ko text: TeamName-->
                            <!--/ko-->
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <img src="Content/Images/liveupdate.gif" />
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-10">
                        <h1><!--ko text: TeamScore--><!--/ko--></h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                <button data-bind="click: $parent.AddScoreToHomeTeam" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="team_plus" style="width: 100%; height:100px">
                    <span  class="glyphicon glyphicon-big glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </button>
```

---

### **UPDATED : Implementation of UpdateLiveScore**

```
        public void UpdateLiveScore(MatchWidget matchdata)
    {
        MatchWidget match = ClubService.AddMatchPoint(matchdata);
        Clients.All.updateLiveScore(match);
    }
```

**MatchWidget Class (viewmodel backend)**

```
public class MatchWidget
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int TeamId { get; set; }
    public string TeamName { get; set; }
    public string OpponentName { get; set; }
    public string LocationName { get; set; }
    public DateTime MatchDate { get; set; }
    public int TeamScore { get; set; }
    public int OpponentScore { get; set; }
    public bool LiveScoreActivated { get; set; } = false;
}
```

The only thing i can think about now is.... is there a datatype mismatch or something which causes this ?

they are specified as int's back-end.. Thoughts ?

Comment: it's asynchronous javascript so self.matchModel() may not be updated before it gets passed back to the server in the call to updateLiveScore.  try using a function callback.

Comment: Is `updateLiveScore` expecting a plain javascript object? You can try mapping the data sent to your update method `ko.mapping.toJS(self.matchModel)`

Comment: Also, FYI - if you only require `TeamScore` and `OpponentScore` to be observables you have gain no benefit from making matchModel an observable. You can just make it a plain javascript object with the same result.

Comment: The code you've posted looks okay to me. Please update the question and include enough code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Updated with more complete code @Jeroen :)

Comment: Posting the implementation of updateLiveScore would really help a lot I guess. Current code seems okay.

Comment: Updated with the back-end code @Adrian Bmrk!.. Can this be a datatype mismatch related problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well.. the solution to the problem here is quite easy, yet.... quite hard to find due to the not-to-easy-to-understand documentation on this topic..

Almost like understanding hieroglyphics in ancient Egypt..

The thing is... that an Observable object with observable properties consists of functions that hold the new values you change.. In my case.. the TeamScore..

No matter how you console.log and debug this through browser debugging it all seems correct, yet.. when you pass the observable object to the server... you won't get the updated data, since this is based on functions (which... is the observable properties inside the observable object)..

So... when reading about serialization and deserialization in the documentation, i came to understand that i needed to serialize the object *before* i sent it to the server, since the values.. was stored in the observable functions..

So the following code example solved this for me :

```
var LiveMatchViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.livematch = ko.observable();
    self.matchModel = ko.observable();

    self.AddScoreToHomeTeam = function () {
        self.matchModel().TeamScore(self.matchModel().TeamScore() + 1);
        var data = ko.toJSON(self.matchModel());
        taskHub.server.updateLiveScore(data);
    }
```

> Take remark of the ko.toJSON(self.matchModel())..

This serializes and stores the changed observables back to the object, generates the JSON and can easilly be passed back as a JSON string to the server..

VOILA!... Problem solved...